# How to create square data frame (or matrix) in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have some IDs 1,3 and 5, how would I create data frame (or matrix) which has those ID's as column/row names, so looking like this:

```
   IDs
 IDS  1  3   5
 1    NA NA NA
 3    NA NA NA
 5    NA NA NA
```

Just a note, those IDs could be any large number, I just took that as example.
Here below is another example, what I'm aiming that. I found this example of data but it was already in .rdata format so I have no clue how to re-create it.

```
              Terms
Terms          applications code computing
  analysis                0    1         0
  applications            9    0         0
  code                    0    9         0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
matrix(nr = 3, nc = 3, dimnames = rep(list(IDS = c(1,3,5)), 2))
#    IDS
# IDS  1  3  5
#   1 NA NA NA
#   3 NA NA NA
#   5 NA NA NA
```

Or if you're golfing

```
matrix(, 3, 3, dimnames = rep(list(IDS = c(1,3,5)), 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a data frame, you could do

```
 tmp <- rep(NA, 3)
 data.frame(ID1 = tmp, ID2 = tmp, ID3 = tmp, row.names = paste('Row', 1:3))
 #       ID1 ID2 ID3
 # Row 1  NA  NA  NA
 # Row 2  NA  NA  NA
 # Row 3  NA  NA  NA
```